# Automatic Height longer works on ItemTemplate since 6.2.0 SDK and more

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have a small problem with the itemtemplate since the update of the SDK 6.2.0 as well as the following SDK ...

before, with the parameter "Ti.UI.SIZE" the cell automatically adapted in height according to the contents.

Since the update, the cell takes the height of the phone screen (equivalent to a "Ti.UI.FILL")

Do you know how to get around the problem?

thank you very much

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a bug in the TiSDK that was fixed in a later version https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-25258

Comment: The solution is to necessarily provide height and width for ALL ALL ALL elements

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in SDK 6.2.X which was fixed in SDK 6.3.0

https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-25258

Comment: The solution is to necessarily provide height and width for ALL ALL ALL elements